# jenkins custom plugin java code to read a file from slave machine

Tags: jenkins-plugins, master-slave

jenkins custom jenkins plugin code is not able to read a file from slave machine . It's throwing FileNotFound exception.

```
FilePath filePath = build.getWorkspace();
boolean isRemoteExecution = filePath.isRemote();
        if (isRemoteExecution) {
                        Callable<StringBuilder, IOException> callable = executeComparison(currentBuildInfo, benchmarkBuildInfo,
                    previousSuccessfulBuildNumber, histogramBuildInfoList, workspaceFolder, jobName, taskListener);
            VirtualChannel channel = launcher.getChannel();
            channel.call(callable);
        }
```

Comment: In the above code the executeComparison method is as below

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{  
  FilePath projectWorkspaceOnSlave = new FilePath(launcher.getChannel(), pathToLocalFile);
  return projectWorkspaceOnSlave.absolutize();
}
```

This works for me